# Is there a simplified framework to consider for modelling the stock market?

Tags: simulations

Does anyone know a reference where one can read up on different aspects of modelling when simulating the stock market? i.e what is known as "stylized facts" and which of these fact that are more interesting then others in different situations.

Moreover I am looking to evaluate an options strategy on a entire index if anyone has some suggestions on which model to pick in that situation. I wanna roll monthly long straddles and so I wanna capture volatility of returns.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. For example, would you like to estimate the returns and covariance matrix and then use Monte Carlo simulations?

Comment: @BobJansen I suppose I just want a model to generate possible outcomes for the index and then do MC on these outcomes. One the one hand one does not want to much dependence on historical data i.e just the one realization of the stock market that happened but will incorporate some properties that are considered universal for a index, maybe I am trying to have my cake and eat it to..

Comment: Do you want to work in $P$ or in $Q$?

Comment: @BobJansen btw is this a good reference? http://rama.cont.perso.math.cnrs.fr/pdf/empirical.pdf . Also are these "stylized facts" canonical and how old is the data on which they are established?

Comment: Hi: I don't know the answer but you should first decide on the time frame you want to consider. The stylized facts are not consistent  if one looks at 1 minute returns versus say yearly returns. ( although mandelbrot might disagree !!!! ).

Comment: @markleeds I am looking to do it as far back as possible rolling monthly options

Comment: My model: "The S&P 500 is a GBM with μ equal 9% a year and standard deviation usually 15% a year but with occasional excursions to 25 or 30% for a few months at a time, and (once a decade) 50%+ for a few days". Is that a simple enough model?

Comment: @noob2 ok, is it possible to sum of the inference and/or considerations(such as stylized facts) you put into that model?

Comment: @user1: I've never seen a diescription of stylized facts for options but I guess they exist. When you say that you want to roll monthly long straddles, that sounds like you're trying to build an options strategy. Does that mean that you're trying to predict returns of options ? I'm not really clear on what you're doing nor too swift on options but maybe if you explained more clearly what you're looking for, someone can help. It's not clear to me how stylized facts will help you with an options strategy.

Comment: @markleeds wanna roll straddler to capitlize on volatility, and so the return would be dependant on the index, I suppose moddeling the options would be pretty much the same thing as modelling the index.

Comment: Based on what you want to do, you better become a volatility expert, then. (Which is a narrower more specific topic than what you are asking about, btw).

Comment: @noob2 my thinking is produce a framework where I can find the right amount to bet in each trade order to max profit in the long run, which is based on probability only in the end. Getting the right "stylized facts" for the monte carlo simulation would help the evaluation. I am assuming certain things about markets in this framework but ill know exactly what I assumed and what it means.

Comment: @user1: It's clearer now but I can't help. thanks for explanation.

Comment: @noob2 that kind of model with 9 % in mean will would probability not make a good represenation of the 1930-1940

Comment: @demully well, almost none, I basically learned how implied vol really is derived and relalised vol. is rather straight forward. Never heard of spot vol. My idea was just to construct some model of the market and use the realisation as training data for a machine learning model to solve my problem and then compare this to the result Kelly betting gives for instance. Moreover I wanna keep some kind of control of the probabilities in every step ans how they develop and not have to much dependance on historic data, since market structure might change significantly, especially these days..

Comment: @demully one could ofc find more sophisticated options positions to capitalize on vol and maybe use trading signals but this is to complicated for me and that also depend on market structure being intact as far as I understand.

Comment: @demully If you have some idea of  vol. exposure and a suitable market model to run it with to produce an optimal strategy id be happy to listen. Id like it to work as some kind of countertrend part of portfoilio, that might cost me a little during calm times but pay off duing chaos. Staddles are pretty crude.